# How to run stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to run a stored procedure in Oracle SQL Developer, but I get an error. I have two parameters, one is statement number (`49028600`), the other returns a cursor with the data. I think my query is not correct. Out parameter is cursor

```
VAR cursor VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN  
    Service.ABC_SERVICE_PACKAGE.FULLSTATEMENT("49028600", cursor);
END

PRINT cursor;
```

Error

> Error report
>   ORA-06550: line 5, column 8:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CURSOR" when expecting one of the following:
>   ;
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: Can you provide the parameter list for the procedure? If the first parameter value is a string, then it should be `'49028600'`. If it's a number, then use `49028600`. If `cursor` is a cursor then it's not a `varchar2`. And it's 'Oracle', not 'Orcale'.

Answer (score 3):

`CURSOR` is a reserved keyword, use a different name for your variable.

Moreover, using double-quotes as in `"49028600"` to wrap up your argument is not allowed, replace with the single-quoted one `'49028600'` or with the one unquoted `49028600` as being a numeric variable.